# How to cancel a running job from the UI?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

Am I missing something but how can I cancel a run in my workspace from https://ms.portal.azure.com/ ? The cancel button is always greyed out.

I know I can use use the sdk to cancel a run using:

```
run = [ r for r in Experiment(ws, 'myExp').get_runs() if r.id == '899b8314-26b6-458f-9f5c-539ffbf01b91'].pop()
run.cancel()
```

But it would be more convenient to be able to do it from the UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of run is this? Canceling is not currently enabled for pipeline runs in the UI, but is supported for other run types.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - yes it is a pipeline run. Is there an ETA when it will be enabled?

Answer (score 1):

Also, faster way to get run by id is
run = Run(ws.experiments["myExp"], "899b8314-26b6-458f-9f5c-539ffbf01b91")